# Replacement char � (FFFD) in URLs

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, unicode, emoji

This question [Why do emoji like 💩 appear when I use Safari, but not Chrome?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41228)

Has a canonical URL of [Why do emoji like 💩 appear when I use Safari, but not Chrome?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41228/why-do-emoji-like-%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bd-appear-when-i-use-safari-but-not-chrome)

Which is an encoded form of ��

It should instead have a canonical URL of [Why do emoji like 💩 appear when I use Safari, but not Chrome?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41228/why-do-emoji-like-%f0%9f%92%a9-appear-when-i-use-safari-but-not-chrome)

Which is a correct encoded form of .

Comment: Oh my goodness, I've been out of the loop for so long I didn't even know about that site.